# nginx - client_max_body_size has no effect

Tags: nginx

nginx keeps saying `client intended to send too large body`. Googling and RTM pointed me to `client_max_body_size`. I set it to `200m` in the `nginx.conf` as well as in the `vhost conf`, restarted Nginx a couple of times but I'm still getting the error message.

Did I overlook something? The backend is `php-fpm` (`max_post_size` and `max_upload_file_size` are set accordingly).

Comment: There is problem with client_max_body_size on SSL enabled. I just got same problem on lasted nginx version and it ignores this directive in secure connections. Still looking for solution.

Comment: In case anyone else googles this: Nginx 1.1.19 (on Ubuntu 12.04) *seems* to ignore client_max_body_size in the 'http' directive, although it's fine with it in 'server'.  This seems to have been introduced in an update in the last 6 months or so, because for me the same config file on the same server used to work.

Comment: @Dave and if you come here in 2018, this seems fixed — `client_max_body_size` in the `http` section has the expected effect with nginx version 1.14.1

Comment: This checks the content length header (at least in 1.4.6), so if a large file is uploaded with unset content length, or content length set to a value less than the max body size, it will not trigger the HTTP 413

Answer (score 162):

Following [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size), you can set client_max_body_size 20m ( or any value you need ) in the following context:

```
context: http, server, location
```

Comment: It didn't work for me in location, worked in the server context. Not sure if it was being overridden, can't say.

Comment: @Dipen: Interesting. What version of NGinx do you have?

Comment: Ditto what Dipen said, except I can't get it in the server{} or location{} blocks... it only works in the http{} context.

Odd

Comment: I can confirm that it only works on nginx/1.4.1 running on Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy) in http{} section.

Comment: Confirming the setting fails when setting on `http` or `location` settings.  Works when set on `server` level.  nginx/1.4.4

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Following the documentation it should work on 3 levels. Maybe you have a counter configuration somewhere?

Comment: @nembleton Not sure.  I added it to `nginx.conf` at `http` and it failed.  I checked `sites-enabled/sites-available` and it wasn't set in any of those configuration files either.  It only worked for me after adding it to the specific `sites-enabled` configuration on the `server` level.  If I tried it in the `location` area, it would fail as well.  Any other place that setting could be set at?  EDIT: And this is pretty much a clean install as well.

Comment: @RobC interesting. The doc mentions 'm'. What system are you on?

Comment: At location level all I can do is reduce the value and not increase it. Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: Have the same with 1.10.1 can reduce file size less than 1m, but can't increase that. So I can use 500k, 600k, but not a 100M or 100m. Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 147):

NGINX large uploads are successfully working on hosted WordPress sites, finally (as per suggestions from nembleton & rjha94)

I thought it might be helpful for someone, if I added a little clarification to their suggestions.  For starters, please be certain you have included your increased upload directive in ALL THREE separate definition blocks (server, location & http).  Each should have a separate line entry.  The result will like something like this (where the ... reflects other lines in the definition block):

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 200M;
}
```

(in my ISPconfig 3 setup, this block is in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file)

```
server {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 200M;
}

location / {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 200M;
}
```

(in my ISPconfig 3 setup, these blocks are in the /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file)

Also, make certain that your server's php.ini file is consistent with these NGINX settings.  In my case, I changed the setting in php.ini's File_Uploads section to read:

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

Note: if you are managing an ISPconfig 3 setup (my setup is on CentOS 6.3, as per [The Perfect Server](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-6.3-x86_64-nginx-courier-ispconfig-3)), you will need to manage these entries in several separate files.  If your configuration is similar to one in the step-by-step setup, the NGINX conf files you need to modify are located here:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

My php.ini file was located here:

```
/etc/php.ini
```

I continued to overlook the http {} block in the nginx.conf file.  Apparently, overlooking this had the effect of limiting uploading to the 1M default limit.  After making the associated changes, you will also want to be sure to restart your NGINX and PHP FastCGI Process Manager (PHP-FPM) services.  On the above configuration, I use the following commands:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
/etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
```

Comment: I would suggest you use `/etc/init.d/nginx reload` instead. This has added benefits such as 'if the config is wrong' NginX won't stop functioning.

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful for me! Solved my problem after hacking around with lots of different php.ini file settings etc.

Comment: Lowercase m worked for us. client_max_body_size 100m;

Comment: @Hengjie I would recommend using `nginx -t` (tests the configuration file syntax) and then `nginx -s reload` (does the actual reload) instead.

Comment: Just need to point out that in my vagrant box there were two ini files - /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini and Symfony's loaded configuration was the fpm one. So don't forget to edit this one.

Comment: In my case you only need to edit the `http { } ` part. I followed your approach and then out of curiosity I removed the directive from `server {}` and `location {} ` and the setting was still valid.

Comment: This does work, but you must run ```sudo service php5-fpm restart && sudo service nginx restart```.  I was able to set just the http {} block, I didn't need to set the server {} or location {} blocks for included virtual hosts.  BUT the config won't reload until you restart both php and nginx, so as a rule I always run the above command if I change either nginx.conf or php.ini.

Comment: For PHP7, Ubuntu 16, the service is called `php7.0-fpm`, not `php-fpm` or `php7-fpm`. Maybe there's some Ubuntu setting that'd have created a 'link' from `php-fpm` to `php7.0-fpm` that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Great solution, this fixed for me in Heroku using NodeJS/Nginx. I'm my case i'm using AdonisJS, and you have to configure the limit: '200mb' and the maxSize: '200mb' in the bodyParser.js config file and finally accept the file size in your code request.file('file', {maxSize: '200mb'});

Comment: If you are already limiting the upload size in `php.ini` then you can disable the nginx 'Content-length' header being set by setting `client_max_body_size` to `0`.

Comment: Similar to the earlier comment I found that adding only to the `location` block was enough.

Comment: It doesn't work in my setup. I have Nginx as a reverse proxy for my ExpressJs (NodeJs) based API server. Nginx uses below 2 config files where I've added this entry /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf so, basically the ssl.conf is getting included in the main nginx.conf for SSL enabled traffic. Any idea why it won't work? My Nginx version is 1.14.1 and it's running on RedHat 7 host

Answer (score 80):

As of **March 2016**, I ran into this issue trying to POST json over https (from python requests, not that it matters).

The trick is to put **"client_max_body_size 200M;" in at least two places  `http {}` and `server {}`**:

**1.** the `http` directory

- Typically in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

**2.** the `server` directory in your vhost.

- For Debian/Ubuntu users who installed via apt-get (and other distro package managers which install nginx with vhosts by default), thats `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com`, for those who do not have vhosts, it's probably your nginx.conf or in the same directory as it.

**3.** the `location /` directory in the same place as **2.**

- You can be more specific than `/`, but if its not working at all, i'd recommend applying this to `/` and then once its working be more specific.

**Remember** - if you have SSL, that will require you to set the above for the SSL `server` and `location` too, wherever that may be (ideally the same as **2.**). I found that if your client tries to upload on http, and you expect them to get 301'd to https, nginx will actually drop the connection before the redirect due to the file being too large for the http server, so it has to be in *both*.

Recent comments suggest that there is an issue with this on SSL with newer nginx versions, but i'm on 1.4.6 and everything is good :)

Comment: The documentation states the default as "1m" which turned out to be 1 megabyte - not 1 megabit. I think - though I haven't yet tested it - it's always megabyte.

Comment: @Thomas yeah it has always been m not M, so it definitely is megabyte, because I ran a test myself.

Comment: Thank you both - i've deleted the bit/byte bit.

Comment: As of 2018 and nginx version 1.14.1, this seems fixed — `client_max_body_size` is honored in section `http` without needing to add it anywhere else.

Comment: @DomQ, You are correct! For nginx version 1.18.0, we added to http body and it worked.  client_max_body_size 20M;

Answer (score 34):

You need to apply following changes:

1. Update `php.ini` (Find right ini file from `phpinfo();`) and increase `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to size you want:

   ````
   sed -i "s/post_max_size =.*/post_max_size = 200M/g" /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
   sed -i "s/upload_max_filesize =.*/upload_max_filesize = 200M/g" /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini```
   ````
2. Update NginX settings for your website and add `client_max_body_size` value in your `location`, `http`, or `server` context.

   ```
   location / {
       client_max_body_size 200m;
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Restart NginX and PHP-FPM:

   ```
   service nginx restart
   service php5-fpm restart
   ```

NOTE: Sometime (In my case almost every time) you need to kill `php-fpm` process if it didn't refresh by service command properly. To do that you can get list of processes (`ps -elf | grep php-fpm`) and kill one by one (`kill -9 12345`) or use following command to do it for you:

```
ps -elf | grep php-fpm | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $4 }' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 16):

Please see if you are setting client_max_body_size directive inside http {} block and not inside location {} block. I have set it inside http{} block and it works

Comment: yes, confirmed, all it needs is the directive in the http block, not the location or the server blocks.

Answer (score 14):

Someone correct me if this is bad, but I like to lock everything down as much as possible, and if you've only got one target for uploads (as it usually the case), then just target your changes to that one file. This works for me on the Ubuntu nginx-extras mainline 1.7+ package:

```
location = /upload.php {
    client_max_body_size 102M;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize=102M \n post_max_size=102M";
    (...)
}
```

Comment: I like this idea too however for me it it does not work this way. All I can do is reduce the the value and not increase it at location level.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem recently and found out, that `client_max_body_size  0;` can solve such an issue. This will set **client_max_body_size** to no limit. But the best practice is to improve your code, so there is no need to increase this limit.

Answer (score 5):

I meet the same problem, but I found it nothing to do with nginx. I am using nodejs as backend server, use nginx as a reverse proxy, 413 code is triggered by node server. node use [koa](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser) parse the body. koa limit the urlencoded length.

> formLimit: limit of the urlencoded body. If the body ends up being larger than this limit, a 413 error code is returned. Default is 56kb.

set formLimit to bigger can solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using Kubernetes, add the following annotations to your Ingress:

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: "5m"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: "8k"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "5m"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "8k"
```

Confirm the changes were applied:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> describe ingress <ingress-name>
```

References:

- [Client Body Buffer Size](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#client-body-buffer-size)
- [Custom max body size](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-max-body-size)

Comment: I tried this but not working. it throws `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: @Andrew what version of Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: It worked for me !

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have already set the client_max_body_size and various PHP settings (upload_max_filesize / post_max_size , etc) in the other answers, then restarted or reloaded NGINX and PHP without any result, run this...

nginx -T

This will give you any unresolved errors in your NGINX configs.  In my case, I struggled with the 413 error for a whole day before I realized there were some other unresolved SSL errors in the NGINX config (wrong pathing for certs) that needed to be corrected.  Once I fixed the unresolved issues I got from 'nginx -T', reloaded NGINX, and EUREKA!! That fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

**Warning for Cloudflare**

Posting this as a warning for other Cloudflare users because I went through the Nginx docs and all the other answers here thoroughly before I finally figured out the issue.

Cloudflare free and Pro plans limit you to 100MB file upload size ([reference](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/maximum-upload-size-is-limit/418490)).

So if the file size is over 100MB Cloudflare will return a 413 response and the request won't ever hit your server.

The solutions suggested are to either use a subdomain that is not proxied through Cloudflare for your upload endpoint or break the file up into chunks that are smaller than 100MB.

Hope this saves someone else some time!

Answer (score 3):

I'm setting up a dev server to play with that mirrors our outdated live one, I used [The Perfect Server - Ubuntu 14.04 (nginx, BIND, MySQL, PHP, Postfix, Dovecot and ISPConfig 3)](https://www.howtoforge.com/the-perfect-server-ubuntu-14.04-nginx-bind-mysql-php-postfix-dovecot-and-ispconfig3)

After experiencing the same issue, I came across this post and nothing was working. I changed the value in every recommended file (nginx.conf, ispconfig.vhost, /sites-available/default, etc.)

Finally, changing `client_max_body_size` in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/apps.vhost` and restarting nginx is what did the trick. Hopefully it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

## *Don't forget to reload nginx :*

###### For RHEL/CentOS/Debian/Ubuntu Linux, try:

```
service nginx reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue that the `client_max_body_size` directive was ignored.

My silly error was, that I put a file inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d` which did not end with `.conf`. Nginx will not load these by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows version nginx, you can try to kill all nginx process and restart it to see.
I encountered same issue In my environment,  but resolved it with this solution.

Comment: That was my issue, thank you! One Nginx instance was not exited properly I guess. It is never bad to check if it is exited on windows ```tasklist /fi "imagename eq nginx.exe"```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried the above options and no success, also you're using IIS (iisnode) to host your node app, putting this code on web.config resolved the problem for me:

Here is the reference: https://www.inflectra.com/support/knowledgebase/kb306.aspx

Also, you can chagne the length allowed because now I think its 2GB. Modify it by your needs.

```
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following config worked for me. Notice I only set `client_max_body_size 50M;` **once**, contrary to what others are saying...

File: `/etc/nginx/conf.d/sites.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name portal.myserver.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /secret/portal.myserver.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /secret/portal.myserver.com.pem;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    server_name portal.myserver.com;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    location /fileserver/ {
        set $upstream http://fileserver:6976;
        proxy_pass $upstream;
    }
}
```