# Php can't upload large files with no error

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file thats 800MB. It start with uploading but at 3% It jumps back to 0%
The second time the upload reach 3% i get "This webpage is not available".
I tried to change the php.ini to this:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 3000M
php_value post_max_size 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 3600
php_value max_input_time 3600
```

But it's still not working.

On my previous server it worked but i have a new one and now it's not working.

How can i fix this?

I found this error:

```
2014/09/18 20:23:26 [error] 5864#0: *332 client intended to send too large body: 732825880 bytes, client: xx.xxx.xx.xx, server: {domain}, request: "POST /upload HTTP/1.1", host: " {domain}", referrer: " {domain}"
```

Comment: It could be in an Apache server's [`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody), although it could also be network issues...

Comment: @Wrikken I think it's not a network issue because it's still working on my previous server.

Comment: ... what makes you think your new server has the exact same physical network as your old server? Are you actively putting the same UTP cable in different NICs? Still, that limitrequestbody seems like it could be one, but loadbalancers / network / firewalls / proxies, everything in between can play a role. That being said: you _did_ examine `phpinfo()` output to verify your php.ini changes stuck?

Comment: @Wrikken Yes I checked phpinfo() And its all changed.

Comment: @Wrikken Where can i change limitrequestbody? Looked in the apache config but couldn't find it.

Comment: If it's not in there, it's not used or limited. I would inspect TCP traffic in that case to see where things go wrong (wireshark et al.), both on the client and server side, as I _assume_ you have enabled full debugging error logs for both Apache & PHP on the server and they don't say anything....

Comment: @Wrikken I found a error, It's edited in the question.

Comment: That looks like you're using `nginx` instead of `apache`, which means you'll have to look into its config and [look at these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056124/nginx-client-max-body-size-has-no-effect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it,

Changed this in the nginx.conf

```
client_header_timeout           1000m;
client_body_timeout             1000m;
client_header_buffer_size       2k;
client_body_buffer_size         1000m;
client_max_body_size            1000m;
```

And now it works! Thank you for your help