# nginx - where can I put client_max_body_size property?

Tags: java, nginx

I need to have a limit of max body size using - `client_max_body_size` property (over nginx.conf) on some url or even globally over my application.

I found this property documented over nginx site:

> ```
> Syntax:   client_max_body_size size;
> Default:  
> client_max_body_size 1m;
> Context:  http, server, location
> Sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body, specified in the “Content-Length” request header field. If the size in
> ```
>
> a request exceeds the configured value, the 413 (Request Entity Too
>   Large) error is returned to the client. Please be aware that browsers
>   cannot correctly display this error. Setting size to 0 disables
>   checking of client request body size.

I need to make this property to a certain part of my app (not globally), so I want to set it to a specified url such as `http://localhost:8088/x/#/y` (# is mandatory)

What is the syntax for this certain url? Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx - client\_max\_body\_size has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056124/nginx-client-max-body-size-has-no-effect)

Answer (score 2):

You can set *client_max_body_size* creating a location block:

```
location = /x {
   client_max_body_size 10M;
}
```

Unfortunately, since the fragment is never sent over http, there is no way to create a *location* block hooking the fragment.

I do not know the logic behind `/x/#/y`, but you could start setting *client_max_body_size* in `/x`.

Comment: that's what I already tried before that, so as you say, I cannot made the url specification for this issue ?

Comment: Fragments are not sent with the request so it seems not feasible in that way.

Comment: My advice is to use a dedicate endpoint for that specific request, way more straightforward