# Upload file limit in Django Nginx Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

When im trying to upload more than 1mb im getting this error:

[image]

I tried configuring my nginx.conf file, I've added this line to inside http { }:

'client_max_body_size 100M;'

and restarted nginx: service nginx restart

but I still get 413 request entity too large.

I feel like I'm missing something because when I tried to search my problem the client_max_body_size solve their problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nginx - client\_max\_body\_size has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056124/nginx-client-max-body-size-has-no-effect)

Comment: nope. tried that.

Comment: I just checked my own nginx configuration: Not sure why, but I have `client_max_body_size 25m;` both in the `http {}` block (in nginx.conf) as well as in my `server {}` block (in my included conf file).

Comment: can you copy the http and server block @dirkgroten?

Comment: I've put them in two separate gists: [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/deegeenl/c754404b57da4f74a3bd82327976861b) and [mydomain.conf](https://gist.github.com/deegeenl/f9602c8e40188f6c8275c3a5a6f7fd86)