# Django REST. File upload due FileField problem with files greater 10 Kb

Tags: nginx, django-rest-framework, file-upload

When I try to save file greater then 10Kb to the server with FileField in Django, I get a 500 error from Nginx.

I've already configured nginx.conf with line "client_max_body_size 20M;" and error changed from 413 to 500.

Files less 10Kb successfully upload to my folder on the server.

*models.py*

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

*serializers.py*

```
class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = '__all__'
```

*views.py*

```
class FileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
```

Comment: Well since the error is from nginx, this has nothing to do with Django: nginx simply never passes the request to the Django server.

Comment: Did you do this in `http`/`server`/`location` https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329327/67579

Comment: Yes, I did it to all of them.

Comment: It's a log of this error:2023/11/24 15:54:26 [crit] 65944#65944: *3 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.40.245, server: projects.local, request: "POST /admin/core/file/add/ HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.10.35", referrer: "http://192.168.10.35/admin/core/file/

Comment: ah, then your Django app runs with a user that has no acces to the files temporarily made by nginx. Probably add the user to `www-data`.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Django isn't a problem maker here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found issue solve.
I had to add this to the nginx.conf: client_body_temp_path /tmp 1 2;
https://github.com/CampbellSoftwareSolutions/docker-osticket/issues/34